# Matrix derivative is invertible.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck with the next exercise.

> Let $f,g:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ functions over $U$. Consider $F:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $H:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x,y)=(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ and $H(x,y)=||F(x,y)||^{2}$. Prove that for all $x\in U$, one of the next two conditions is not fulfilled.
>
> 1. $H$ attains a local maximum at $x$
> 2. The derivative of $F$ at $x$ is invertible, i.e., the matrix $DF(x)$ is invertible.

My idea was to proceed by contradiction, i.e., suposse that there exist $x_0\in U$ such that (1) and (2) holds. For this, (1) means that there exist $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $z\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$, $H(z)\leq H(x_0)$. Moreover, $\nabla H(x_0)=\overline{0}$. Here, $$\nabla H(x_0)=\left(2 f(x_0)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0)+2g(x_0)\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_0), 2 f(x_0)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0)+2g(x_0)\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x_0) \right)=(0,0)$$By (2), $DF(x_0)$ is an invertible matrix. Then
$$DF(x_0)=\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0) & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0)\\ 
  \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_0) & \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x_0)
\end{pmatrix}$$
Beign invertible, then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0)\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x_0)-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0)\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_0)\neq 0$.
But, from here, I don't know how to continue. Maybe we can join the two conditions to derive a contradiction, but it's not clear to me. Any hint? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to manipulate the $\nabla H(x_0)$ equation as follows:

$$2f(x_0) \frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x} = -2g(x_0)\frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x}$$

$$2f(x_0) \frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial y} = -2g(x_0)\frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial y}$$

Divide the top equation by the bottom equation:

$$\frac{\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial y}} = \frac{\frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial y}} $$

Then you get the contradiction when you cross multiply and compare to the 2nd equation.  You may need some special cases for when one of the partials is zero so that you aren't dividing by zero.